# angular ngSubmit doesnt work (button inside and module imported)

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I'm a beginner with angular testing the framework for the first time.

I have a simple form

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <label for="test">Test Prompt: </label>
   <input type="text" id="test" name="test">
   <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

and a component just made with ng generate:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css']
})
export class HomepageComponent {
  constructor(){}
  onSubmit() {
    alert('test');
    console.log('Form submitted successfully!');
  }
}
```

however nothing logs to the console and no alerts pop

I have also added the module in app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomepageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: how is your component invoked?

Comment: I think it's because you need to add the `[formGroup]` directive to your form - `ngSubmit` is an output of that directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an answer to better explain with minimal example.

In your component:

```js
form = this.fb.group({});

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
```

then in your template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="...">
```

Edit: Check out the Form Group Directive documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective)

Comment: You're welcome! Also, check the (very good) [reactive forms guide](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) in the docs